# How to update table with the help of another look-up table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to perform a db change. I have two table set up as follows: the lookup is a temporary lookup table i created. The I add a new column called cur_format as well, but it empty.

```
Currency
_______
[cur_format] [nchar](10) NULL,
[cur_format_old] [int] NULL
[other_data]  [int] NULL
cur_format_old   cur_format  other_data
0                             565656
1                             498985
2                             145126
3                             236124
2                             789565
4                             784512


Lookup
__________
[cur_format] [nchar](10) NULL,
[cur_format_old] [int] NULL
cur_format_old      cur_format
0                   USD
1                   GBP
2                   AUD
3                   CAD
4                   CNY
```

After update, I want the currency table be like this:

```
Currency
   ______
cur_format_old  cur_format    other_data
0               USD           565656
1               GBP           498985
2               AUD           145126
3               CAD           236124
2               AUD           789565
4               CNY           784512
```

The lookup table have about 100 rows. And the Currency table is fairly large, therefore, I want to use script to update the table.
How do I achieve that in sql-server? Many thanks

Comment: can you give the schema for the currency table. IE wil lit support a char or nvarchar, and if so how large?

Comment: Why would you denormalize your table?

Comment: Your `Currency.cur_format` is listed as type `int` if I'm reading your shcmea correctly.  You can't set it to varchar values `USD`,`GBP`, etc

Comment: The whole thing does not make any sense. Is it your real task or simplification? What is the use case you are trying to accommodate?

Comment: Doesn't look like the order of currencies in the existing table matter...no need for the lookup table. Could you just create a new table with the values needed, drop the old, then rename? Or just drop and recreate, skipping the rename?

Comment: @Fred I have renamed the Currency.cur_format to cur_format_old, and add a column called cur_format with type [nchar](10). I am stuck on inserting value based on the lookup table and the cur_format_old

Comment: @beargle I have a fair large Currency table, so I want to use script to update the db

Comment: Your `Currency` table still shows *only* a `cur_format` column with a data type of `int` which can't contain varchar values.  Please update your question or give consideration to @beargle 's suggestion

Comment: @Zen It doesn't matter how _big_ the `Currency` table if it has the same definition as what was posted in your question. Why not drop and recreate the table?

Comment: @beargle sorry. I wasn't clear before. I hav other column in the currency table as well, which I don't want to lose.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an `update` with a `join`:

```
update c
    set cur_format = l.cur_format
    from currency c join
         lookup l
         on c.cur_format_old = l.cur_format_old;
```

This will only update the values that match between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said this doesn't make any sense. You seem to be denormalizing your database. It has also been noted that with the current datatype this won't work. Leaving all rational consideration behind it is possible to do what you ask. Again, this seems like a VERY bad idea to me but here is a complete script including changing datatype.

```
alter table Currency
    add NewFormat varchar(3)

update Currency
set NewFormat = l.cur_format
from Currency c
join MyLookup l on l.cur_format_old = c.cur_format


alter table Currency
    drop column cur_format

EXEC sp_rename 'Currency.NewFormat', 'cur_format', 'COLUMN';

select * from Currency
```